# reboot and shutdown command freeze on my Ubuntu vivid 15.04

Tags: 15.04, shutdown, freeze, reboot

Every time I have to reboot or shutdown the display keeps on showing the image of Ubuntu with the dots that keeps on going.
Even with command from the terminal.
I have to press the button to power off my laptop all the times.

My Laptop is an HP Compaq nx6310 32bit

Someone have a solutions?

PS: I have the kernel version 4.2.1 final release

Thanks in advance

Luca Tansini

Answer (score 0):

First this may be [bug #1464917:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917)

If this affects you please go there and let them know by clicking "This affects me" link above the initial bug description.

After the shutdown or reboot has hanged with this message.

`Reached target Shutdown`

You may only see this if you have removed the splash screen.  If the system has hanged for any reason you can use this method.

Try [Sysrq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

1. Hold down the Alt and SysRq (Print Screen) keys.
2. While holding those down, type the following keys in order, several
   seconds apart: REISUB
3. Computer should reboot.

Once it reboots immediately try shutdown button again, it should shutdown properly.  Please add your name to the "This Affects Me" button at launchpad bug link above if you think this is the same issue.

You can also try the following after it hangs.

Try and login tty1 and reboot

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or `Ctrl+Alt+F2` or `Ctrl+Alt+F3` ...
2. Write your username (lowercase, the name of the user folder in
   /home) and hit Enter
3. Write your password (nothing will appear) and hit Enter

If your password and username are correct, you are now logged in.

If that fails try `Ctrl+Alt+Del` a couple times at that point in the tty1 screen

You might see a message that states the machine is going to reboot and then it should do just that after a minute or so.

Its better than a hard boot - until its fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I resolve the problem for almost every reboot. Only when I change kernel at the reboot I have the same problem.

Comment: @LucaTansini  Can you explain how you resolved the issue by editing your question or add an answer, the info could help me and others with this issue

Comment: Sorry, but from yesterday I have the same problem with reboot that takes hours and hours until I use the shutdown button on the laptop.